# Append output to file?

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, xslt, append

Currently my script is not appending but deleting my existing files. How can I append my output to an existing (.csv) file? Or can't I append my reuslt to a file.
I am transforming every xml with every xsl file to csv files (i get xml*xsl csv files at the end). I only want to have as many csv files as I have xsl files.

```
C:
$converter = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
foreach ($xsl in (Get-ChildItem (Join-Path (Get-Location) "Users\fh0054\Desktop\powershell\xsl") -filter "*.xsl")) {
  $converter.Load($xsl.FullName); 
  foreach ($xml in (Get-ChildItem (Join-Path (Get-Location) "Users\fh0054\Desktop\powershell\xml") -filter "*.xml" )) {
    $converter.Transform($xml.FullName, (Join-Path (Get-Location) ("Users\fh0054\Desktop\powershell\csv\" + $xml.Name + $xsl.Name + ".csv")));
  }
}
```

(I hope one can understand what I mean by that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Appending output to an file you can use the below command:

```
$Path="Full Path of file"
"Content you want to out file" | Out-file $Path -Append
```

Hope this HElps.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: The question was regarding how to append output to a file without deleting it.  I hope the above answer serves the purpose.

If not, let me know what exactly you are looking at?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably make some sort of temporary file where you store your data and then append new files data to it. Should be looking something like this:

```
$tempcsv = 'c:\temp\my.csv'
$converter = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;

foreach ($xsl in (Get-ChildItem (Join-Path (Get-Location) "Users\fh0054\Desktop\powershell\xsl") -filter "*.xsl")) 
{
  $converter.Load($xsl.FullName); 
  foreach ($xml in (Get-ChildItem (Join-Path (Get-Location) "Users\fh0054\Desktop\powershell\xml") -filter "*.xml" )) 
  {
    $path = (Join-Path (Get-Location) ("Users\fh0054\Desktop\powershell\csv\" + $xml.Name + $xsl.Name + ".csv"))
    $converter.Transform($xml.FullName, $path);
    Import-Csv $path | Export-Csv -Path $tempcsv -Append -NoTypeInformation
  }
}
```